# Web scraper that can scroll down to load more of a page?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am learning a bit about webscrapers and would like to make a webscraper that can look for offers on steam. Steam has got its own page where it has all of its offers, so I could just scrape that for the best offers, but it only loads a specific amount and you have to scroll further down to load more, and then you have to scroll even further down again and again. How would a webscraper be able to get those offers, that only load when you scroll further down?

Comment: Could you give a link where you want to scroll down?

Comment: Here is the link to the page on which I want to scroll down: https://store.steampowered.com/search/?specials=1